# Obtener información de una variable node.js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Tengo una función en la cual quiero actualizar un dato solo cuando se cumpla una condicion en caso contrario mandar un vacio.
Esta es mi funcion:

```
router.put('/orders/change-status/:id', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
const { status} = req.body;
const tracking = [];
if( status == 'SHIPPING'){
    tracking.push({trackingUrls:'/orders/view/'+ req.params.id});
    tracking.push({trackingCodes:['1,2,3,4']});
}else{
    tracking.push({trackingUrls:''});
    tracking.push({trackingCodes:''});
}
const trackingUrls = tracking.trackingUrls;
const trackingCodes = tracking.trackingCodes;

await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { status, trackingUrls, trackingCodes});
res.redirect('/orders');
```

});

Estoy almacenando en una constante llamada tracking y posteriormente lo quiero recuperar en sus respectivos nombres trackingUrls y trackingCodes me responde un null cuando se realiza el proceso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

La variable `tracking` es de tipo `Array`. Cuando haces `tracking.trackingUrls` siempre te dará `undefined` porque `trackingUrls` no es una propiedad de un [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución al problema es que declares tu variable como [Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

```js
let tracking = { ... };
```

Y en vez de usar el método `push()` que pertenece a `Array`, puedes usar la asignación directa usando corchetes:

```js
tracking['trackingUrls'] = ... ;
```

O notación de punto:

```js
tracking.trackingUrls = ... ;
```

Por otro lado, la sentencia `else` sobraría si inicializas las propiedades al momento de crear el objeto. Por ejemplo:

```js
router.put('/orders/change-status/:id', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    const { status} = req.body;
    const tracking = {
        trackingUrls: '',  // <- aqui inicializas la propiedad
        trackingCodes: ''
    };
    if( status === 'SHIPPING'){  // <- acostumbra a usar ===
        tracking['trackingUrls'] = '/orders/view/'+req.params.id;
        tracking['trackingCodes'] = ['1,2,3,4'];
    }
    const { trackingUrls, trackingCodes } = tracking;  // <- destructuración de variables.
    // la linea anterior es equivalente a las dos siguientes:
    // const trackingUrls = tracking.trackingUrls;
    // const trackingCodes = tracking.trackingCodes;
    
    try {
        await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { status, trackingUrls, trackingCodes});
        return res.redirect('/orders');
    }
    catch(e) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: 'Algo salió mal durante la consulta'
        });
    }
});
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

**Nota:**

Siempre que trabajes con [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) usando [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), debes envolver tu código en un bloque [`try ... catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), para evitar que una excepción no controlada (en caso de que una Promesa sea rechazada) finalice tu aplicación.